# Webpack v5 custom setup. My javscript doesn't minify when building for production

Tags: webpack, minify, webpack-5, es5-compatiblity

My project used to minify the Javascript for production but now that I check it again, it does not. I have moved around plugins and edited various things to try and get it working again but I can't. Please can someone help me?

I also set `target: ['web', 'es5']` but that doesn't convert the javascript to es5.

I imagine the order I load things in causes this issue but I can't figure out what exactly.

`webpack.config.js`

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require("image-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: "./src/app",
    },
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        assetModuleFilename: "[name][ext]",
        clean: true,
    },
    target: ["web", "es5"],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ["html-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            postcssOptions: {
                                plugins: [["postcss-preset-env"]],
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                type: "asset",
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                type: "asset/resource",
            },
        ],
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new CssMinimizerPlugin()],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "src/index.html",
            meta: {
                description: {
                    name: "description",
                    content:
                        "A calculator used to work out the maximum travel distance according to the speed, temperature, temperature control and wheel size",
                },
            },
        }),
        new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
            minimizerOptions: {
                plugins: [
                    ["mozjpeg", { quality: 72 }],
                    ["pngquant", { strip: true, quality: [0.7, 0.7] }],
                ],
            },
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    ],
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
    },
};
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "sendcloud-technical-assessment",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "...",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode=development",
        "build": "webpack --mode=production"
    },
    "author": "...",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
        "html-loader": "^2.1.2",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
        "image-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
        "imagemin-mozjpeg": "^9.0.0",
        "imagemin-pngquant": "^9.0.2",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.2.0",
        "postcss": "^8.3.6",
        "postcss-loader": "^6.1.1",
        "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
        "sass": "^1.37.5",
        "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "webpack": "^5.50.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "normalize.css": "^8.0.1"
    }
}
```

And finally the output when I run the build script

```
> webpack --mode=production

assets by chunk 172 KiB (auxiliary name: index)
  assets by path *.woff 97.4 KiB 3 assets
  assets by path *.woff2 75 KiB
    asset montserrat-bold-webfont.woff2 25.2 KiB [compared for emit] [from: src/assets/fonts/montserrat-bold-webfont.woff2] (auxiliary name: index)
    asset montserrat-regular-webfont.woff2 24.9 KiB [compared for emit] [from: src/assets/fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff2] (auxiliary name: index)
    asset montserrat-light-webfont.woff2 24.8 KiB [compared for emit] [from: src/assets/fonts/montserrat-light-webfont.woff2] (auxiliary name: index)
assets by path *.png 441 KiB
  asset hero-image@2x.png 301 KiB [compared for emit] [from: src/assets/images/modules/hero/hero-image@2x.png] [minimized] [big]
  asset hero-image.png 84.8 KiB [compared for emit] [from: src/assets/images/modules/hero/hero-image.png] [minimized]
  asset car-base@2x.png 42.1 KiB [compared for emit] [from: src/assets/images/modules/calculators/car-base@2x.png] [minimized]
  asset car-base.png 12.7 KiB [compared for emit] [from: src/assets/images/modules/calculators/car-base.png] [minimized]
assets by chunk 35.1 KiB (name: index)
  asset bundle.js 20.8 KiB [compared for emit] (name: index)
  asset index.css 14.3 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: index)
asset index.html 75.1 KiB [compared for emit]
Entrypoint index 35.1 KiB (172 KiB) = index.css 14.3 KiB bundle.js 20.8 KiB 6 auxiliary assets
orphan modules 19.9 KiB [orphan] 6 modules
cacheable modules 20 KiB (javascript) 20 KiB (css/mini-extract)
  ./src/app/index.js + 5 modules 20 KiB [built] [code generated]
  css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css 5.99 KiB [built] [code generated]
  css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/index.scss 14 KiB [built] [code generated]

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  hero-image@2x.png (301 KiB)

WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

webpack 5.51.1 compiled with 2 warnings in 3788 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to spread the default optimizations as well.

```
optimization: {
    minimizer: [new CssMinimizerPlugin(), "..."],
},
```